# What's the difference between ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 & ffmpeg-snapshot-git.tar.bz2 on ffmpeg.org

Tags: ffmpeg, website

On [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) when you go to  “Download > Download Source Code” it gives you `ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2`

But if you click on “Get the Sources”, git snapshot it gives you `ffmpeg-snapshot-git.tar.bz2`  on ffmpeg.org.

What's the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference, if you look inside, is that `ffmpeg-snapshot.tar` contains *only* the latest source code, while `ffmpeg-snapshot-git.tar` contains the latest source *and* a `.git` subdirectory containing the entire commit history in Git format (i.e. the same data that would be downloaded using `git clone`).

```
$ tar -tf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 > a
$ tar -tf ffmpeg-snapshot-git.tar.bz2 > b
$ diff -u a b
--- a   2022-10-02 21:16:03.931276283 +0300
+++ b   2022-10-02 21:16:24.891340188 +0300
@@ -1,4 +1,97 @@
 ffmpeg/
+ffmpeg/.git/
+ffmpeg/.git/FETCH_HEAD
+ffmpeg/.git/HEAD
+ffmpeg/.git/ORIG_HEAD
..
+ffmpeg/.git/objects/pack/pack-d90600a253862355b70c4f1d14e3e5de1a99c820.idx
+ffmpeg/.git/objects/pack/pack-d90600a253862355b70c4f1d14e3e5de1a99c820.pack
..
```

(The reason for publishing a .git tarball instead of `git clone` is that the former is a static file download that can be interrupted and resumed whenever needed, while the latter – even when done via HTTP – is a dynamic download served by Git as a CGI server, which does not support resuming an interrupted clone.

However, once you've performed the initial large "clone via tarball" once, the same dynamic Git protocol will let you efficiently download or `git pull` all *new* commits since the last update. Because of this, a Git-tarball only needs to be re-published every month or so, depending on daily commit rate. In comparison, a normal "source snapshot" tarball needs to be re-published nightly otherwise there's not much point to it.)

Answer (score 0):

It says on [the website](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#get-sources) under the **git** snapshot.

> Development branch snapshots work really well 99% of the time so
> people are not afraid to use them.

TL;DR:
It's the development branch.